# Postgis cannot open out of db dted file

Tags: postgis, raster

I import a dted file into a postgis enabled database with the -R option.
I also gave the complete directory path to the file.
I also have the raster and gdal related environment variables on the system.
When executing a sql query that must use the dted data I get the following error:

```
rt_band_load_offline_data Cannot open offline raster
```

With the full path of where the file is.
Any ideas what the problem could be, or how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you manage to find a fix for this?

Answer (score 3):

Very likely you ran into the default setting of postgis on enabling out-db rasters. Try adding this in front of your query:

> SET postgis.enable_outdb_rasters TO True;

Read more in this blog [post](http://postgis.net/2015/05/02/tip_enable_raster_drivers/) and in the [docs](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/postgis_enable_outdb_rasters.html).

Comment: didn't work for me.

Comment: This solves a different problem to the question asked. i.e. once the outdb_rasters is true, if postgis can't open the file then this is the error message that occurs

Answer (score 1):

If the file definitely exists, then the problem is probably file permissions (or permissions in a folder where the file is).

In my case I am mounting a volume to a Docker container where I'm runing PostGIS

```sh
docker run -v /var/lib/some-dir/:/var/lib/some-dir .... etc
```

And the PostGIS process running in the container was not allowed access to the /var/lib/some-dir folder on the host machine.

**To test if this is the problem**

Try changing the permissions on the file/folders. In my case:

```sh
chmod -R 777 /var/lib/some-dir/*
```

Then I found that my PostGIS out of DB raster was accessible.

(Don't leave folders or files with `777` permissions)